# How to fold a wide plot into multiple lines using ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to show the x-axis labels and the form of the line clearly on this plot. It is a [point plot with a lot of categories along the x-axis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ySPT8.jpg) which makes the plot very wide and very hard to read the x-axis.

Would it be possible to fold the plot in half and display it on two panels, one above the other?  How would I do that? I thought about hacking around with `facet_wrap` but this got ugly with the ordered points (as I wish to maintain the order of the x-axis based on the value).

Or are there better ways of showing this data? The position of the categories along the x-axis is of interest, as is the shape of the line formed by the points.

I generated the example plot using this code:

```
library(stringi)
example <- data.frame(
  cat = do.call(paste0, Map(stri_rand_strings, n=150, length=c(25, 14, 13), pattern = c('[A-Z]', '[0-9]', '[A-Z]'))), 
  val = rnorm(150, mean = 20)
)

cat_ordered_by_val <- example$cat[order(example$val)]
example$cat = factor(example$cat, levels=cat_ordered_by_val)

ggplot(example, aes(y = val, x = cat)) + 
  geom_point() +
  ylab("Value") + xlab("Category") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust=1, size=5))

ggsave("~/Desktop/what_a_plot.jpg")
```

Comment: This is going to be a poor visualization, even in you fold the x axis. Do you really need all the x axis labels? You could make a very attractive and informative plot by removing the x axis labels and directly labelling only the points of interest. Who will be the audience? Is it a presentation, a report, paper, a journal aritcle? A table would be far easier to read here, with a plot just for illustration of the shape of the distribution. Splitting it into two lines even loses that message.

Comment: You are probably right.  For now it is just to show my supervisor before reviewing how/if we want to publish this view of the data. I could just make a wide image for now for discussion with them. If we were to publish, then just showing the first 5 and last 5 might be an option. What's the best way of achieving that?

Answer (score 0):

This puts points in one of the two facets in alternating ways. You can also do `mutate(facet = row_number() < nrow(example) / 2)` to put the first half of the points in one facet and the other half in the other facet:

```
library(tidyverse)

example <- data.frame(
  cat = do.call(paste0, Map(stri_rand_strings, n = 150, length = c(25, 14, 13), pattern = c("[A-Z]", "[0-9]", "[A-Z]"))),
  val = rnorm(150, mean = 20)
)

cat_ordered_by_val <- example$cat[order(example$val)]
example$cat <- factor(example$cat, levels = cat_ordered_by_val)

example %>%
  arrange(cat) %>%
  mutate(facet = row_number() %% 2) %>%
  ggplot(aes(y = val, x = cat)) +
  geom_point() +
  ylab("Value") +
  xlab("Category") +
  theme_bw() +
  facet_wrap(~facet, ncol = 1, scales = "free") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust = 1, size = 5))
```

[image]

Comment: This hasn't maintained the order of the x-axis though, as the facet is on row number rather than the order used in the category.

Comment: @jakobo I've revised my answer. You can use shorter category names and a `tibble`. This reduces the likelihood that others interpret 'order is of interest' differently.

Comment: I am not sure I follow, the updated example still changes the order of the x-axis.  We are interested in the sorted order of the categories with respect to the value.

Comment: Maybe `fct_inorder` after `mutate` helps